# I can't change the state of a div when i click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

My HTML/CSS:

```css
.elements > div i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div id="state" onclick="changestate()">
     <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
     <span class="object"> Λάμπα </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And when i click on the div, i want to apply these styles instead

````css
.elements > div i {
    color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}

Can someone help me with this? I spent many hours but couldn't make it! I am using an external js file, and the code is this:

```js
function changestate() {
  document.getElementById("state").style.color = "rgba(49, 69, 106, 1)";
  document.getElementById("state").style.boxShadow = "inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
  document.getElementById("state").style.border = "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)";
}
````

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the style of the `i` element, you shouldn't change the style of `document.getElementById("state")`. You can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab the `i` element inside of the `div` and style that. Check the snippet below:

```js
function changestate()
{
  document.querySelector("#state i").style.color = "rgba(49, 69, 106, 1)";
  document.querySelector("#state i").style.boxShadow = "inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
  document.querySelector("#state i").style.border = "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)";
}
```

```css
div i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div id="state" onclick="changestate()">
   <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
   <span class="object"> Λάμπα </span>
</div>
```

I would probably add a new style in the CSS file and toggle that class name instead of the hard coded styles though. You can use [`.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for that.

```js
function changestate() {
  document.querySelector("#state").classList.toggle('pressed');
}
```

```css
div i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.pressed i {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -0.5px -0.5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
}
```

```html
<div id="state" onclick="changestate()">
  <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
  <span class="object"> Λάμπα </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! so all i had to do was to use the querySelector and find whats the i element and use it in the javascript?

Comment: `querySelector()` is just another way to select an element, and in this case it's easier to use. But you have to select the `i` element if you want to style that.

Comment: ok, i understood! Thank you! Can i ask something else? If i wanted to use an if statement  in this function how would u suggest to do it? example: if color: rgba(49, 69, 106, 0.6) then color = rgba(49, 69, 106, 1) else to leave it as it is

Comment: Instead of if-statements, you should create a class and toggle that on clicks. Check the second snippet. Is this code for a checkbox?

Comment: It's something like a button, i want it to be pushed and when i click again, to come back in the previous state! This code doesn't seem to work for me, maybe i am doing something wrong

Comment: Hmmm your code works for sure! The problem for me is that my css has .elements > div i  and not just div i. That's why it doesn't work for me. How could i define that in javascript?